# How to open the parent dir of the current file in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Like what `:Ve` and `:E` did, but in NERDTree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
:NERDTree %
```

Works for me. % is the path to the current file, so you can't cd to %, but NERDTree interprets it intelligently and opens the folder instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the "`:NERDTree`" / "`:NERDTreeToggle`" commands?  Check out:

```
:help NERDTreeFunctionality
```

Comment: It seems :NERDTree opens the `pwd` where VIM started.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to automatically cd to the current file always. This works with NERDTree.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_to_the_directory_of_the_current_file

```
function AlwaysCD()
  if bufname("") !~ "^ftp://"
    lcd %:p:h
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufEnter * call AlwaysCD()
```

Comment: I don't get it. Added to my .vimrc, nothing changed.
I have to type `lcd %:p:h`, then opens :NERDTree?